# Mouseout doesn't work on parent > child

Tags: jquery

I have this full demo code. I'd like to **show a blue div when mouseover the green div and hide the blue div when mouseout the green div**. The problem is when I mouseover green and move up on the blue, the mouse is actually out of the green area but the blue doesn't disappear. How to fix the problem?

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on({
            mouseover: function(e){
                $(".inner").show();
                $(".message").text("OVER");

            },
            mouseleave: function(e){
                $(".inner").hide();
                $(".message").text("OUT");
            }
        }, ".outer");
    });
    </script>
    <style>
    .outer {
        padding: 20px;
        background: green;
        margin: 50px 0 0 0;
    }

    .inner {
        display: none;
        background: blue;
        height: 30px;
        width: 300px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 8;
        top: 25;
    }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="outer">
            OUTER
            <div class="inner">INNER</div>    
        </div>
        <div class="message"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a shorter solution:

```
     $(".outer").hover(function () {
    $(".inner").show();
}, function () {
    $(".inner").hide()
});

$(".inner").hover(function () {
    $(".inner").show();
}, function () {

    $(".inner").hide();

});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jM6GM/2/)**

`.hover` seems to work magic in such situations.

Comment: This code doesn't work. Try to move the mouse from top to bottom. The blue div disappears when the mouse still in the green.

Comment: I updated my code and jsfiddle. Am I getting closer?

Comment: Nah, because this is just a demo. In my real case the elements doesn't exist on the beginning. I mean it's dynamic so you have to use "on" event handler.

Comment: Working perfectly! Thank You! <3

Answer (score 0):

Over lapping mouseovers are bit of a problem but this should work:

```
var inner_active = false;
$(document).on({
            mouseover: function(e){
                if(!inner_active){                    
                    $(".inner").show();
                    $(".message").text("OVER");
                }
            },
            mouseleave: function(e){
                inner_active = false;
                $(".inner").hide();
                $(".message").text("OUT");
            }
        }, ".outer");

$(".inner").on({"mouseover": function(e){
            inner_active = true;

            },"mouseleave": function(e){
           $(this).hide(); 
}});
```

Here we only active the inner div only if we haven't entered the outer div from inside the inner div.
http://jsfiddle.net/Mm3sn/

Comment: Your code has a small problem. When I move the mouse from the bottom to top, the blue appears then disappears. Imagine the blue is a tooltip, the blue shouldn't disappear then the mouse is still in the green.

Answer (score 0):

This [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/UV446/) could be a solution.
In this way, when you leave the green div even if you are on the Blue div, Blue div disappears

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('mousemove',function(event){
     if(isOver($('div.outer'), event )){
         $('div.inner').css('display','block')
         }else{
            $('div.inner').css('display','none') 
             }
      })
   function isOver( element, e ) {
        var left = element.offset().left,
            top = element.offset().top,
            right = left + element.width(),
            bottom = top + element.height();
        return ( e.pageX > left && e.pageX < right && e.pageY > top && e.pageY < bottom );
  };
})
</script>
```